# python multiprocessing - child process blocking parent process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to learn multiprocessing, and created an example, however it's behaving unexpectedly.
the parent process run, then create a child process, but resources doesnt go back to parent until child is done.

code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def f():
    newTime = time.time() + 7
    while(time.time() < newTime):
        print("inside child process")
        time.sleep(int(5))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bln = True
    while(True):
        newTime = time.time() + 4
        while(time.time() < newTime):
            print("printing fillers")
            if(bln):
                p = Process(target=f)
                p.start()
                p.join()
                bln = False
```

result

"inside child process"

(wait for 5 sec)

"inside child process"

"printing fillers"

"printing fillers"

[...]

If I remove 'p.join()' then it will work. But from my understanding, p.join() is to tell the program to wait for this thread/process to finish before ending the program.
Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Dont' do the join until you are ready to wait for the child process to complete. I don't understand your code's intent well enough, but normally, one would keep a list of processes and join them outside of the while after all work is done. Your code looks like it will create a huge number of processes for 4 seconds, though.

Comment: No wait, it'll exit the loops after 1 child process. What is your intent with the code? This is written to create one child process and wait for it, and that's what it does.

Comment: @tdelaney what I want to do in my actual program, is set off a process to run on its own after certain condition is met. Parent doesn't care what the child process do or when it end. Child will finish all his task then end.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve the problem. By default python will wait for the child when the parent exits regardless of a specific join. You can set `daemon=True` when creating the process... but I think the child process will be destroyed when the parent exits. I may be wrong about that... anyway, maybe running a subprocess instead would be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you @tdelaney, I actually have it working, I just want to understand why having that join() will make it not work. I will take a look at subprocess, maybe it is more suitable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But from my understanding, p.join() is to tell the program to wait for
> this thread/process to finish before ending the program.

Nope, It blocks the main thread right then and there until the thread / process finishes. By doing that right after you start the process, you don't let the loop continue until each process completes.

It would be better to collect all the `Process` objects you create into a list, so they can be accessed after the loop creating them. Then in a new loop, wait for them to finish only **after** they are all created and started.

```
#for example
processes = []
for i in whatever:
    p = Process(target=foo)
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

If you want to be able to do things in the meantime (while waiting for `join`), it is most common to use yet another thread or process. You can also choose to only wait a short time on `join` by giving it a timeout value, and if the process doesn't complete in that amount of time, an exception will be thrown which you can catch with a `try` block, and decide to go do something else before trying to `join` again.

Answer (score 0):

p.join() isn't for ending the program, it's for waiting for a subprocess to finish.  If you need to end the program, use something like sys.exit(0) or raise SystemExit('your reason here')